# google maps real time traffic

Tags: json, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps web-services -> Distance Matrix API.
My goal is getting driving time between two or more fixed locations, but considering real-time traffic.

I have tried a couple of parameters combinations, but I always get a static trip duration on the replied JSON.

Do you have a recommendation regarding building a request for getting back tip duration considering real-time traffic?

Comment: You should post what your have tried and be more specific about what solution your are looking for. This will help people see the direction you're headed in and provide an answer that fits.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following request on a browser, in order to get a JSON reply:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?&origins=Guadalajara&destinations=Chapala&mode=driving&departure_time=now

However, the parameter "duration" is always the same:

```
duration    
text    "54 mins"
```

I would like to get the trip duration considering real time traffic as part of the replied JSON, like when using Google Maps on web:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Guadalajara,+Jal./Chapala,+Jal./@20.4809265,-103.3652921,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x8428b18cb52fd39b:0xd63d9302bf865750!2m2!1d-103.3496092!2d20.6596988!1m5!1m1!1s0x842f40b1771f4cb7:0x73c1721b67d87f53!2m2!1d-103.1846016!2d20.3051576!3e0

Comment: Add the API key in your request and you will get `duration_in_traffic` field in the response.